# Express Router not able to find path '/'

Tags: node.js, express, get, controller, router

Been wondering what i have been doing wrong. i have created router file with following code

````
const router = express.Router()
const userController = require('./controllers/userController')
router.get('/', userController.home)
router.post('/buyNow', userController.buyNow)
module.exports = router```



for some reason it is showing can not get '/'
````

Comment: Can you also share how have you configured `express`?
Are you importing this router at any place and including in express app configuration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure express in start script(index.js) as below

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
app.use('/', userRouter);

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server started')
});
```

and for routing purpose you can create a router file(user.js)

```
const router = express.Router();

const userController = require('./controllers/userController');

router.get('/', userController.home);

router.post('/buyNow', userController.buyNow);

module.exports = router;
```

If you still observe **can not get '/'**, there might be some error either at your start script or controller. Try to check logs at terminal.

Comment: thank you so much Kind stranger , app.use('/', router)
 worked for me